# Possible cookie attack

Tags: cookies

I am testing an web application and I found a cookie in which the language of the application is set. Specifically, I have modified one request and I have noticed that all the other requests it makes keep the value that I set in the belly. I wanted to know if it is possible to exploit this behavior in some way.

Comment: So you're saying you set `lang=foo` and the server responds with `lang=foo`?

Comment: Exactly. More precisely **Cookie: cookieName=original_value;** and I modify it **Cookie: cookieName=modify_value** This value modified  is always modified in subsequent requests.

Comment: I guess there's no way to know, you need to try. For example putting special chars the language string (special in HTML or SQL), then browsing the site to check if anything breaks.

Comment: The only attack vector i know crlf injection in such a scenario